# jquery disable controls and alert on click

Tags: jquery

I have an asp.net 4.0 page using jquery and jquery UI and ajax.

Problem: The page may be displaying a data where the record is flagged as non-editable (in code, not from a SQL Server db record state). FYI: The page would be flagged at the time it is loaded from the server, not based on some user input.

When flagged as non-editable I need to do a number of things to the page.

Disable a number of select and text inputs and buttons.

When the user attempts to edit (or clicks) those controls I need to display an alert.

Can someone help me with the slickest way to accomplish this?

Would I just apply a class to all those controls and then have jquery events tied to the class?

Comment: You have logic problem here: once you disable some element, there is no click event on that element. It's disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabled form elements don't fire the `click` event, but their *parent* elements may still see it. You can hook the `click` event of the *container* of those fields (the `form`, for instance), and then look to see which element was clicked (via the `event.target` property, which jQuery makes sure is set correctly cross-browser). If it's one of these disabled elements, you can do your alert:

```
$("selector_for_the_form").click(function(event) {
  if (event.target.disabled) {
    alert("You can't click the " + event.target.name + " field");
  }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/elimo5)

This will only work on browsers that create the event and let it propagate. Firefox and Opera don't; IE and Chrome do.

Rather than *disabling* the form fields, though, you might consider setting them `readonly` instead. [Details here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-readonly). That makes things much more reliable ([live example](http://jsbin.com/elimo5/4)).

Answer (score 1):

Edit: just realised the top of your post says ASP sorry :P
But theres probably other ways to do that same thing using ASP

You may have to toggle the readonly state of any textboxes or inputs you are using.

If you are using PHP you can pass a variable via GET and use that to tell elements to be readonly or even disabled.

E.G.

```
<input type="textbox" name="box01" <?php if ($_GET["disable"]==true) {echo 'readonly="readonly";} ?> />
```